# How to enable hover tool in bokeh, python.I cant get the hover tool to work in seaborn library in python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

The hover tool doesn't work in python jupyter notebook. it shows the data correctly but doesn't hover and show the details coded in TOOLTIPS when needed.

By default, the hover tool will generate a “tabular” tooltip where each row contains a label and its associated value. The labels and values are supplied as a list of (label, value) tuples. For instance, the tooltip below on the left was created with the accompanying tooltips definition on the right.

`$index`
index of selected point in the data source

`$name`
value of the name property of the hovered glyph renderer

```
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Name', 'Overall', 'Wage', 'Value'])
df1

def value_to_float(x):
    if type(x) == float or type(x) == int:
        return x
    if 'K' in x:
        if len(x) > 1:
            return float(x.replace('K', '')) * 1000
        return 1000.0
    if 'M' in x:
        if len(x) > 1:
            return float(x.replace('M', '')) * 1000000
        return 1000000.0
    if 'B' in x:
        return float(x.replace('B', '')) * 1000000000
    return 0.0

wage = df1['Wage'].replace('[\€,]', '', regex=True).apply(value_to_float)
value = df1['Value'].replace('[\€,]', '', regex=True).apply(value_to_float)

df1['Wage'] = wage
df1['Value'] = value

df1['Difference'] = df1['Value'] - df1['Wage']

df1.sort_values('Difference', ascending=False)




TOOLTIPS = [
    ('index', "$index"),
    ("Wage", "$Wage"),
    ("Value", "$Value"),
    ("Name", "@Name"),
]

p = figure(title="FIFA 2019", x_axis_label='Wage', y_axis_label='Value', plot_width=700, plot_height=700, tools='hover,wheel_zoom', tooltips=TOOLTIPS)
p.circle('Wage', 'Value', size=10, source=df1)
show(p)
```

Comment: seaborn is based on matplotlib. bokeh is its own thing from both of those entirely. they don't mix.

Comment: Ya, but i need all three to make my data work

Comment: The Bokeh hover tool will only work on the Bokeh plot. After you expecting it to work with the others? (It won't) Or are you saying it's not working on the Bokeh plot? It's not clear. If the latter, clarify and simplify the question to remove all the irrelevant parts about other libraries.

Comment: @JezonFernando that seems unlikely. in any case, you're not using seaborn or matplotlib in your example, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See if you ran all code parts, before that block, which are neccessary for it to work, for example if you only run last block it will trow error df1 is undefined, so you need to run block in which you defined df1 first

Comment: Using the [edit] button and adding an explanation would make your answer more valuable.